# Cypher Query Labguage Neo4j, Iterative functions

Tags: function, cypher, iteration

I have a database with ~1'000,000 nodes, each node has two principal properties: mass and lev, I have lev 1 to 50, and I want to find de biggest node (given by mass) in each lev, my start node can be anyone, there is some kind of iterative function or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

there are no iteration in the pure cypher, either you do it in an upper lvl language who uses cypher or you define the starting node manually using an index:

```
START n1=node:levIndex('lev:1') WITH max(n1.mass) as mx MATCH n1 where n1.mass=mx RETURN Id(n1),n1.mass;
START n2=node:levIndex('lev:2') WITH max(n2.mass) as mx MATCH n2 where n2.mass=mx RETURN Id(n2),n2.mass;
START n3=node:levIndex('lev:3') WITH max(n3.mass) as mx MATCH n3 where n3.mass=mx RETURN Id(n3),n3.mass;
.....
```